# How to styling the HTML5 desktop Notification?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, notifications

i try to make desktop notification for my web,
i found [this](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/10/desktop-notification-like-facebook-using-html5/) guide usefull to make it with.
and successfully done it.

i post the code here too:

html:

```
<button id='button'>Notify me!</button>
```

js:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(notifyMe);

function notifyMe() {
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  } else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    var options = {
      body: "This is the body of the notification",
      icon: "icon.jpg",
      dir: "ltr"
    };
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there", options);
  } else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
      if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
        Notification.permission = permission;
      }

      if (permission === "granted") {
        var options = {
          body: "This is the body of the notification",
          icon: "icon.jpg",
          dir: "ltr"
        };
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there", options);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/iofirag/kxh603n7)

**my question is**, there is a way to change the default style of it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid it's not possible to edit more than what you're doing. like alert elements, it's the browser who format the notifications.

Comment: Agreed. There are some more options you can add, but none can configure the background. [Notification Options](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#type-NotificationOptions)